# Can I set default page to last page when paginating in Laravel 4?

Tags: pagination, laravel

In laravel 4, it's really convenient to do pagination. When the page parameter is missing, the default page is the first page. In my project, it's better to be the last page as default value.

Currently I'm using following **UGLY** way to hack the pagination. Is there any better way to do this?

```
if(!Input::get('page') && $comments->getLastPage() > 1)
    //Redirect with page=lastPage
```

And the question can be also asked as that can I set the current page of paginate() function manually? If no, what can I do if I don't want the page parameter to be named `page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live with setting the pagination manually:

```
// check if a page is set
if(!Input::get('page'))
{
    // work out the last page
    $lastPage = ceil($totalItems/$perPage);
    // set the page - maybe merge would be better than replace???
    Input::replace(array('page' => $lastPage));
}
// manually create the paginator
$paginator = Paginator::make($items, $totalItems, $perPage);
```

I don't know what you're displaying, but would reversing the sorting not work?

[Paginator docs](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination)

Comment: I've done it in similar way, redirecting with `page=$lastPage` instead of replace the value in `Input`.